# Разбить строку по регулярке, сохранив делитель в java/kotlin

Tags: php, java, android, регулярные-выражения, kotlin

Если очень кратко, то я хочу конвертировать управляющие символы ANSI (цвета) в html, который потом можно было бы использовать в TextView. Однако, для этого нужно разбить строку на токены и собрать html код. С этим у меня и возникли проблемы

```
text.split(Pattern.compile("(\\u001B\\[[\\dm;]+)")).forEach { token -> 
    Log.i("token", token)
}
```

Есть сей код на котлине, но но удаляет цвета из массива.

Актуальный результат: `["red"]`

Ожидаемый результат: `["\u001B[38;5;203m", "red", "\u001B[m"]`

На php это выглядело бы так:

```
$string = "\e[38;5;203m" . "red" . "\e[m";
var_dump(preg_split("/(\e\[[\dm;]+)/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
```

Comment: Вы лучше добавьте текст + ожидаемый результат в вопрос. Такая у вас строка: [`val s = "\\e[38;5;203mred\\e[m"`](http://rextester.com/FEJI63115)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew обновил

Comment: *я хочу конвертировать управляющие символы ANSI (цвета) в html* - вот это нужно проиллюстрировать. Мне кажется, что нет нужды разбивать текст на части, нужно сразу найти и заменить.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Каким же образом? Проблема в том, что цвет может быть не один и "\e[m" сбрасывает цвета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код для Kotlin, который разбивает строку на части с помощью *целого* регулярного выражения:

```
private fun splitKeepDelims(s: String, rx: Regex, keep_empty: Boolean = true) : MutableList<String> {
    var res = mutableListOf<String>()  // Объявляем изменяемый список
    var start = 0                      // Задаём переменную для начала подстроки
    rx.findAll(s).forEach {             // Ищем все совпадения
        val substr_before = s.substring(start, it.range.first()) // Подстрока до начала совпадения
        if (substr_before.length > 0 || keep_empty) {
            res.add(substr_before)      // Добавляем подстроку до начала совпадения
        }
        res.add(it.value)               // Добавляем совпадение
        start = it.range.last()+1       // Обновляем начало следующей подстроки до совпадения
    }
    if ( start != s.length ) res.add(s.substring(start)) // Если есть текст после последнего совпадения, добавляем
    return res
}
```

[Пример использования](http://rextester.com/NDEO79204):

```
val s = "\u001B[38;5;203mred\u001B[m\u001B[38;5;203mgreen\u001B[m"
val rx = """\u001B\[[\dm;]+""".toRegex()
var res = splitKeepDelims(s, rx, false)
println(res)
```

Результат:

```
[[38;5;203m, red, [m, [38;5;203m, green, [m]
```

Comment: Не будет ли пустых строк в массиве?

Comment: @frago Я добавил необязательный аргумент для метода `splitKeepDelims`.